# Compilation problem with the nuitka module in python

Tags: python, compilation, exe, nuitka

I've made a python program and I'd like to put it in .exe format to share it with others. I installed the nuitka module and tried to compile my file.py file into an exe with the command :
`python -m nuitka --disable-conole --onefile file.py`
The command prompt starts compiling and stops on this error, which I don't understand and which I'd like to resolve:

collect2.exe: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.

Thanks

I searched the internet but couldn't find anything that matched my requirements.

Comment: It stops on... what error? Please read [ask].

Comment: This is the error :
collect2.exe: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.